# Local SQL Server Backup Exception in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, exception, backup

I have a local SQL Server database. Every time I want to take a backup, an exception occurs, I don't know how to handle it - please help me!

Here is my Code :

```
Public Function DBBackUp(DB_Address As String, Bckup_Address As String) As Boolean
        Try
            Dim ComStr As String = "BACKUP DATABASE [" & DB_Address & "] TO DISK = N'" & Bckup_Address & _
                         "' WITH NOFORMAT, INIT, NAME = N'MData" & _
                         "-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10 "
            MyConnection = New SqlConnection(strConnection)
            MyCommand = New SqlCommand(ComStr, MyConnection)
            If MyConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then MyConnection.Open()
            MyConnection.ChangeDatabase("Master")
            SqlConnection.ClearAllPools()
            MyCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("An Error Occurred." & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
            Return False
        Finally
            MyCommand.Dispose()
            If MyConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then MyConnection.Close()
        End Try
    End Function
```

Exception message is :

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding. The backup or restore
>   was aborted. 10 percent processed. 20 percent processed. 30 percent
>   processed. 40 percent processed. 50 percent processed. 60 percent
>   processed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Set the connection timeout in your connection. This timeout is exceeded due to a command which needs more time to process. Please tell me if it works

Comment: do you mean The Connection timeout in Connection String ?! i also set that to 30 and 60 and 120 but did not work ! still same exception occurs - plus "70 percent processed". :-(

My Connection String : 
Public Con_Str As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" & DirDataBase &
        ";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"

Comment: How long is your Statement running? You have to measure the time

Comment: 28 Seconds! is Timeout Really Helpful ?
my Database Has about 1,000 Rows! I Don't Think this is Too Hard for Database to back them up! is it ?!

Comment: Can you please post the full stacktrace of the exception?